# Formatting a date in a file as per the specified format

Tags: java, date, csv

I am parsing a csv file which consists of three colums as shown below

```
GHF FGH DATE
AAA BBB 20-Aug-2013     
CCC DDD 16-Sep-2013
```

I am able to successfully parse it , but in addition I need to add
validation  in a java class that the date format in csv file should be of `20-Aug-2013` as shown above.  If I recieve the date in some other format then I must throw a exception.

Please advise how to achieve this .

Answer (score 2):

You can use `SimpleDateFormat` from `java`.

[Here](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0040__Data-Type/SimpleDateFormat.htm) is an example available:

```
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy");
String myDate = format.parse(myString).toString();
```

Answer (score 1):

The format in the `SimpleDateFormat` should be like :

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy");
```

and then

```
Date testDate = sdf.parse(date);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `SimpleDateFormat` to parse the date string as per your format. Make sure you do `setLenient(false)`. It will throw a `java.text.ParseException` if the date is not as per format you specify.

```
 SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy");
 sdf.setLenient(false);
        try {
            Date d = sdf.parse("06-AUG-2012") ;
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            System.out.println("Date is in invalid Format!");
        }
```